# Tableau: calculated field after data is reshaped

Tags: tableau-api

I'm trying to wrap my head around how to created a calculated field in Tableau that is calculated *after* the source data is pivoted. My source data is "long" i.e. normalized and looks like this:

```
+---------+---------+-------+
| Company | Measure | Value |
+---------+---------+-------+
| A       | Sales   | 100   |
+---------+---------+-------+
| A       | Exp     | -10   |
+---------+---------+-------+
| B       | Sales   | 200   |
+---------+---------+-------+
| B       | Exp     | -30   |
+---------+---------+-------+
```

(Actually every company would have more than two records, but this is simplified)

What I'd like to get out is the following where `Net` is calculated as `Sales + (2 * Exp)`.

```
+---------+---------+-------+-------+
| Company | Sales   | Exp   | Net   |
+---------+---------+-------+-------+
| A       | 100     | -10   | 80    |
+---------+---------+-------+-------+
| B       | 200     | -30   | 140   |
+---------+---------+-------+-------+
```

I can get the following by simply having `Company` as my row and `Measure` as my column and then `sum(Value)`:

```
+---------+---------+-------+
| Company | Sales   | Exp   | 
+---------+---------+-------+
| A       | 100     | -10   |
+---------+---------+-------+
| B       | 200     | -30   | 
+---------+---------+-------+
```

But how do I calculate an additional column based on the result of pivoting `Measure`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this get you what you need?

The crux is creating calculated fields for `Exp` and `Sales` like this:

`Exp =`
`if [Measure] = "Exp" then [Value] end`

`Sales =`
`if [Measure] = "Sales" then [Value] end`

Those become measures you can use as the columns. 
[image]

Comment: I like it... but there's something I'm missing. When I try this I get an error: "reference to undefined field [Sales]" because `Sales` is not a field in the source data. What sorcery did you do to help Tableau 'see' the `Sales` column which is really a pivot of the `Measure` field.

Comment: I'm sorry, I think I misunderstood your question and that you're connecting to the data already reshaped. If you're connecting to it normalized, then this should do the trick. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60455118/150929%20stackoverflow.twbx

Comment: my data is "long" and I do the reshaping inside of Tableau. So I don't think you misunderstood. Thank you for the example workbook. What version was it created with? I'm on 8.2 and getting an error that I'm not new enough.

Comment: It was created with 9.0. You can download a version here to open the file. http://www.tableau.com/esdalt 
Otherwise recreate your Sales and Exp formulas with the following: `if [Measure] = "Exp" then [Value] end`
and `if [Measure] = "Sales" then [Value] end`. Then get the Net is `Sum([_Sales]) + sum([_Exp] * 2)`

Comment: ohhhh. yes that makes sense. I was able to recreate in 8.x. Using `IF` statements makes sense. I had not thought of doing it that way.